# Mongoose model.save() not persisting to database on update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing a mongoose / node.js / express app.

in my routes I am using [express' app.param()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) method to get my model instance into the request - instead of fetching it in each controller action.

i got `show` and `create` actions working in my controller - however I am stuck implementing the `update` action.

here is my relevant controller code:

```
// mymodel-controller.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel');
var utils = require('../../lib/utils');

"use strict";

exports.update = function (req, res, next) {

  var mymodel = req.mymodel;
  mymodel.set(req.body);
  mymodel.slug = utils.convertToSlug(req.body.title);

  mymodel.save(function(err, doc) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('update successful');
       // here i see the correctly updated model in the console, however the db is not updated
      console.dir(doc); 
      return res.redirect('/mymodels/' + mymodel.slug);
    } else {
      console.error('update error', err);
      return res.render('mymodels/edit', {
        title: 'Edit Model',
        model: mymodel,
        errors: err.errors
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The strange thing is, the mongoose save goes through successfully, I don't get any error.
I see 'update successful' and the correctly updated model printed on the console, but not persisted in the database.
I tried also fetching the model manually before updating and saving it, instead of using app.param(..) but I had the same effect.
Any idea what I am missing here?

**update**

this is the code where I set the `req.mymodel` - part of a longer routes file.
In my show actions e.g. I also use req.mymodel to display it and it works fine so far.

```
/**
 * mymodel ROUTES
 */
app.param('mymodel', function(req, res, next, id){
  MyModel.findOne({ 'slug': id }, function(err, mymodel) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else if (mymodel) {
      req.mymodel = mymodel;
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(404).render('404', {title: "Not found", errorMessage: "The requested mymodel was not found."});
    }
  });
});
app.get('/mymodels',                 mymodelsController.index);
app.get('/mymodels/new',             mymodelsController.new);
app.post('/mymodels',                mymodelsController.create);
app.get('/mymodels/:mymodel',        mymodelsController.show);
app.get('/mymodels/:mymodel/edit',   mymodelsController.edit);
app.put('/mymodels/:mymodel',        mymodelsController.update); // that's the one not working with the code above
app.del('/mymodels/:mymodel',        mymodelsController.destroy);
```

**update2**

This code, on the other hand, works in my controller and updates the database (I'd much prefer using instance.save() though)

```
exports.update = function (req, res, next) {

  var mymodel = req.param('mymodel');


  var query = { slug: mymodel };

  var update = {};
  update.title = req.param('title');
  update.body = req.param('body');
  update.points = req.param('points');
  update.location = req.param('location');
  update.slug = utils.convertToSlug(req.param('title'));

  MyModel.update(query, update, function (err, numAffected) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    if (0 === numAffected) {
      return next(new Error('no model to modify'), null);
    }

    res.redirect('/mymodels/' + update.slug);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code which sets `req.mymodel`?

Comment: Admittedly, I've mistakenly looked in the wrong collection more than once when I had multiple similarly named collections (and had forgotten Mongoose's automatic naming conventions for collections).

Comment: WiredPrairie: I'm sure its the right collection, I have only 2 atm ;) @robertklep: updated question with that code part

Comment: @frankblizzard one reason why changes aren't picked up is when you're setting properties that aren't being declared in the schema. However, since you say that the object returned by `save` shows the correct (updated) doc, that shouldn't be the issue here (but still worth mentioning)

Comment: robertklep: that might be the case as I am just doing a model.set(req.body) and req.body also contains _csrf field afaik. i will look into this, thanks already

Comment: no, no luck. also when i just try to change only one field it does not persist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed the way I set the `req.param` value in my routes.

Instead of doing this in my routes file:

```
app.param('mymodel', function(req, res, next, id){
  MyModel.findOne({ 'slug': id }, function(err, mymodel) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else if (mymodel) {
      req.mymodel = mymodel;
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(404).render('404', {title: "Not found", errorMessage: "The requested mymodel was not found."});
    }
  });
});
```

I had to declare a controller action that loads the instance each time, like

```
app.param('mymodel', mymodelController.load);
```

which pretty much looks like in [this example](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/app/controllers/articles.js#L15-L24).